# Discord.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a support system but an error occurred in my `presenceUpdate` event. Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance

PS: I am French and I use a translator, please excuse my imprecisions.

> Event presenceUpdate.js :

```js
module.exports = (client, oldMember, newMember, newPresence) => {
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
      let { soutien_role_id: soutienRoleId, soutien_text: soutienText } = client.db.settings.selectSoutien.get(guild.id);

      if(soutienRoleId && soutienText) {
        
        if (!oldMember) return;
        if (oldMember === undefined || newMember === undefined) return;
        if (oldMember.status !== newMember.status || oldMember == undefined || newMember == undefined) return;
        if (guild.members.cache.get(newMember.user.id) === undefined) return;
        
        const soutienRole = guild.roles.cache.get(`${soutienRoleId}`);
        const word = soutienText
        const members = newMember.guild.members.cache;
        let status = members.filter(m => m.presence?.status !== "offline")
        status = Array.from(status)
          
        if(!members) return;
        
        if(status[0] && status[0].includes(word)) {
            members.roles.add(soutienRole)
          } else {
            if(guild.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === soutienRoleId)) {
              guild.members.roles.remove(soutienRole)
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
```

> Error :

```js
{
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
    at C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\\src\\events\\presenceUpdate.js:24:35
    at _Collection.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\\src\\events\\presenceUpdate.js:2:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:537:28)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\        
ode_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\actions\\PresenceUpdate.js:37:19)
    at module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\
ode_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\websocket\\handlers\\PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\      
ode_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\websocket\\WebSocketManager.js:346:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\
ode_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\websocket\\WebSocketShard.js:478:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\
ode_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\websocket\\WebSocketShard.js:317:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\\Users\\smonf\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Bots Discord\\New Projects\\- MyCorp\\archive-2022-06-25T114850Z\
ode_modules\\ws\\lib\\event-target.js:199:18)"
}
```

Comment: `guild.members.roles` roles isn't a property of `guild.members` , are you trying to remove the role from oldMember or newMember?

Comment: I trying to remove the role from newMember

Comment: try `newMember.roles.remove(soutienRole)` instead of `guild.members.roles.remove(soutienRole)`

Comment: The error has not changed...

Comment: The error means newMember.roles is undefined, i'd try and figure out why - check what it returns and why it's undefined

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'oldMember, newMember' with 'oldPresence, newPresence' for better understanding([presenceUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate)) and try this:

```
newPresence.member?.roles.remove(soutienRole)
```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'member')

Comment: Can you share your event handler? I think there is a problem with the handler.

Comment: The event handler has been posted as an answer

Comment: I don't know. But it might be related to your variables("client" as "oldPresence", "oldMember" as "newPresence" etc.). You can check it with `console.log()`. Because this one works fine for me: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VAbTV06k).